# ruby hash merge with a block

Tags: ruby, hash

Trying to use ruby Hash merge! on multiple hashes, starting with an empty hash

```
a = {}
b = {x: 1.2, y: 1.3}
c = {x: 1.4, y: 1.5}
fact = 100 # need to multiply values that are merged in with this
a.merge!(b) {|k,v1,v2| v1 + v2 * fact} # it doesn't multiply values with     fact
a.merge!(c) {|k,v1,v2| v1 + v2 * fact} #it does multiply values with fact
```

So first merge does not give me result I was expecting, while the second merge does. Please note that in real app keys are not limited to x and y, there can be many different keys.

Comment: Re-submit your code without irb-prompts.

Comment: Further to @sagarpandya82's comment, not only do the IRB prompts make it harder to read but everyone who cuts and pastes your code must clean it up before doing anything with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first merge works as described in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21).

The block is invoked only to solve conflicts, when a key is present in both hashes. On the first call to [`Hash#merge!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21), `a` is empty, hence no conflict occurred and the content of `b` is copied into `a` without any changes.

You can fix the code by initializing `a` with `{x: 0, y: 0}`.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. Unfortunately, I can't initialize hash a, there may be many different keys in any of the hashes, not just x and y. Now understanding that "the block is invoked only to solve conflicts", I think I am gonna use a workaround multiply values in another block before handing it to the hash merge, then use straight
    
    a.merge!(c) {|k,v1,v2| v1 + v2}

Comment: If the keys you use in the hashes are not fixed then I think you probably should not use `merge` but implement the merge yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to perform the merge as follows.

```
a = {}
b = {x: 1.2, y: 1.3}
c = {x: 1.4, y: 1.5}
[b, c].each_with_object(a) { |g,h| h.update(g) { |_,o,n| o+n } }.
  tap { |h| h.keys.each { |k| h[k] *= 10 } }
  #=> {:x=>25.999999999999996, :y=>28.0}
```

Note that this works with any number of hashes (`b`, `c`, `d`, ...) and any number of keys ({ x: 1.2, y: 1.3, z: 2.1, ... }`).

The steps are as follows<sup>1</sup>.

```
e = [b, c].each_with_object(a)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [{:x=>1.2, :y=>1.3}, {:x=>1.4, :y=>1.5}]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can see the values that will be generated by this enumerator by applying [Enumerable#entries](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries)<sup>2</sup>:

```
e.entries
  #=> [[{:x=>1.2, :y=>1.3}, {}], [{:x=>1.4, :y=>1.5}, {}]]
```

We can use [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to generate the first value of `e` and assign the two block variables to it (that is, "pass `e.next` to the block"):

```
g,h = e.next
  #=> [{:x=>1.2, :y=>1.3}, {}]
g #=> {:x=>1.2, :y=>1.3}
h #=> {}
```

Next we perform the block calculation.

```
f = h.update(g) { |_,o,n| o+n }
  #=> {:x=>1.2, :y=>1.3}
```

Here I have used the form of Hash.update (aka `merge!`) which employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. (See the doc for details.) As `h` is now empty (no keys), the block is not used for this merge.

The next and last value of `e` is now generated and the process is repeated.

```
g,h = e.next
  #=> [{:x=>1.4, :y=>1.5}, {:x=>1.2, :y=>1.3}]
g #=> {:x=>1.4, :y=>1.5}
h #=> {:x=>1.2, :y=>1.3}
f = h.update(g) { |_,o,n| o+n }
  #=> {:x=>2.5999999999999996, :y=>2.8}
```

Since `g` and `h` both have a key `:x`, the block is used to determine the new value of `h[:x]`

```
_ #=> :x
o #=> 1.4
n #=> 1.2
h[:x] = o + n
  #=> 2.6
```

Similarly, `h[:y| = 2.8`.

The last step uses [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) to multiple each value by `10`.

```
f.tap { |g| g.keys.each { |k| h[k] *= 10 } }
  #=> {:x=>25.999999999999996, :y=>28.0}
```

`tap` does nothing more than save a line of code and the creation of a local variable, as I could have instead written:

```
h = [b, c].each_with_object(a) { |g,h| h.update(g) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
h.keys.each { |k| h[k] *= 10 }
h
```

Another option (that does not use `tap`) is to write:

```
f = [b, c].flat_map(&:keys).uniq.product([0]).to_h
  #=> {:x=>0, :y=>0}
[b, c].each_with_object(f) { |g,h| h.update(g) { |_,o,n| o+10*n } }
  #=> {:x=>26.0, :y=>28.0}
```

<sup>1 Experienced Rubiests: GORY DETAIL ALERT!</sup>

<sup>2 [Hash#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-to_a) could also be used here.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for a detailed description of an advanced solution. I guess question sparked some interest in finding an elegant solution for this problem.

Comment: Thank you, Shreko, but as you gain experience with Ruby you will come to view my approach as merely workman/workwoman-like.